# Casting on HoloLens using RenderTexture and MediaCapture frame using Unity

Tags: image-processing, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to work on a casting feature for hololens with out using the inbuilt mixed reality capture.

I have attached a secondary camera as a child of the Main camera and I am taking a snapshot of the camera view to a render texture and saving it as a PNG. At the same time I am taking a frame from the HoloLens camera using Media Capture. And after I get both the images I am combining them to one single image. The media capture output image is 1280x720 and the render texture image is 640x360. So before combining the image I am reducing the size of the media capture output to 640x360 as well. But in the combined image, The alignment of the hologram is wrong. There is an offset in the position. Any idea on what might be causing this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider enabling ‘**Render From PV Camera**’ to align holograms.

[image]

Additionally, you can refer to [Enabling improved alignment for MRC in your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/mixed-reality-capture-overview#enabling-improved-alignment-for-mrc-in-your-app) to learn more details.